# Reference on Functional Monotone Class Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a textbook with a general version of a Functional Monotone Class Theorem. Recall that this theorem says that if $\mathcal A$ is rich enough set of bounded functions and $\mathcal H \supset\mathcal A$ is closed under taking limits then under some extra conditions $\mathcal H$ contains all bounded functions.

Where in the literature can I find this statement and its proof?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at *Probability with Martingales* by D. Williams. A functional MCT appears on page 37 (Theorem 3.14). 
See also p. 10 in E. Cinlar's *Probability and Stochastics* and p. 276 in R. Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*.

A variant for cones of non-negative functions can be found on pages 44-45 of D. Pollard's *A User's Guide to Measure Theoretic Probability*.